# Updating event start date from FullCalendar into my database results in 00:00:00

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar and attempting to update an event start time when a user drags and drops an event in my calendar. This is the code I am using attached to the eventDrop callback (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop):

```
        alert(info.event.id + ' was dropped on ' + info.event.start);
        $.ajax({
          url: '/Post/dropPost',
          type: 'POST',
          data: { 'postSchedule': info.event.start, 'postId' : info.event.id },
        });
       },
```

This works in as much as the alert shows the correct event ID and the correct start date (in the following format: Tue May 05 2020 04:36:00). The '/Post/dropPost' method is also called and the postId variable is passed fine.

However, when it updates my database the postSchedule always updates as "00:00:00 00:00:00".

This is my dropPost method:

```
    public function dropPost() 
    {
        $data=[];
        $postSchedule = $_POST['postSchedule'];
        $postId = $_POST['postId'];
        $droppedPost = new PostModel;
        $data['id'] = $postId;
        $data['postSchedule'] = $postSchedule;
        $droppedPost->save($data);
    }
```

From reading the FullCalendar documents my understand is that that dates should always be ISO8601 standard: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing. So why does it not translate into my database.

The postSchedule column in my database is type DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I needed to use .toISOString() on the info.event.start property.

Working code is as follows:

```
 eventDrop: function(info) {
    alert(info.event.id + ' was dropped on ' + info.event.start);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/Post/dropPost',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { 'postSchedule': info.event.start.toISOString(), 'postId' : info.event.id },
    });
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I think is that you're not converting the `postSchedule` in correct format to be stored in the `database`. 
**Controller**
First, check that the data is being retrieved by `print_r($this->input->post())`.
 If yes, then convert the data in correct form ie `$data['postSchedule'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($postSchedule));` and then store the data in `database` with type `DATETIME`.

Hope this helps you.